# uRapidFlow Force Images Import

Tags: import, image

We have updated our source images and need to reimport them into Magento. Does anyone know how to force uRapidFlow to import all images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only solution to force a refresh of the gallery images is to remove and add the image in the profile. We created two rows for each image. Then we prefixed the first row with - so -CPI will delete the image. The second row will add it, again.

ie

```
-CPI,SKU-1,i/m/image1.jpg
CPI,SKU-1,i/m/image1.jpg,"Image 1 label",1,0 
-CPI,SKU-2,i/m/image2.jpg
CPI,SKU-2,i/m/image2.jpg,"Image 2 label",1,0 
-CPI,SKU-3,i/m/image3.jpg
CPI,SKU-3,i/m/image3.jpg,"Image 3 label",1,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Export a list of your SKUs and the associated images (rapidflow export profile is recommended)
Make your changes to the images (change or directory/rename?)
Create a new product import profile and upload your corrected csv.

This assumes that your setting up your import profile properly.
Under Import Options there should be a section for Image Options. Set auto-import to yes and set your local import folder (or remote folder)

Comment: The image has been edited. There is no change to the image filename.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to import just base, small and thumbnail image? Then use regular profile and you can update them. You can select to delete old images to clear up some space as well.
If you have only modified files without name change, then you can directly overwrite old image files, or still use a profile to import the image files.